# Tree structure with image and text, use CSS to Align text after overflow

Tags: css, alignment

In creating a custom tree, I am using a image followed by a label. The issue is when the label overflows it goes under the image, rather I need it to be aligned with the starting point of text. How do I do that with css.

Sample code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="maindivclass">
        <ul>
            <li id="TR_239984" class="liclass">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x16" class="imgclass" />
                <label class="labelclass">This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge</label>
            </li>
            <li id="TR_239985" class="liclass">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x16" class="imgclass" />
                <label class="labelclass">This is another long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please check a sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcmKg/)**

I need to make it look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEnCs.jpg

I need image and text seperate because clicking either does 2 different things, so cant use background image for list style, unless its possible using that also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcmKg/1/)

```
li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

li img {
    position: absolute;
}

li label.labelclass {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I didnt realize using relative+absoulte positioning can have this effect.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect time to use CSS floats. Float both the image and the label to the left and give them defined widths. Make sure to "clear" the float on the .liclass

See http://codepen.io/imjared/pen/EDgHc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.maindivclass {
    width: 300px;
}

li { 
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    list-style: none;
}

.img_container {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li label.labelclass {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<li id="TR_239984" class="liclass">
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="img.png" class="imgclass" />
    </div>
    <label class="labelclass">
        This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge
    </label>
</li>
```

I added a class .img_container because it just simplified setting the width without skewing the img.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/ZcmKg/8/)

Comment: Thank you, this also works good, but I am having some issues with using float, (i need to learn more of css) :)

Answer (score 0):

Hear I give you the best code for it.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box-one">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x16" />
    </div>
    <div class="box-two">
This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge. This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edgeThis is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge.      
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


     <div class="box-one">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x16" />
    </div>
    <div class="box-two">
This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge. This is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edgeThis is a long text to show wrapping of the text from the box edge.       
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
.wrapper{
    width:800px;
    background:#E6E6E6;

}
.box-one{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.box-two{
    float:right;
    width:750px;
}
```

Hope this definitely helps you. Cheer.